# Does heartbleed have any effect if OpenSSL was only used to generate the certificate

Tags: windows, certificates, openssl, heartbleed

**Edit: Please follow the above link to the original.**

I have a self-signed certificate which is use to sign other certificates that I issued. This is all done with an affected version of OpenSSL. These certificates are installed on Windows servers for encryption of https traffic. OpenSSL is NOT installed on the servers. From what I understood, heartbleed only affects servers which directly use OpenSSL to encrypt the traffic. Is this correct or am I still vulnerable?

Comment: No, you are not vulnerable.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/55188/2630). Basically all questions that ask "is [non TLS component] affected by Heartbleed?"

Comment: @Lekensteyn Thank you for the link, that does answer my question.

Comment: @Lekensteyn : Please put that as an answer so that it can be validated by OP

Comment: @ack__ It's better to reduce the number of duplicate questions, so please vote for closure.

Comment: @Lekensteyn I agree, except the linked answer should have a better title. It's title basically a list its tags. I'm sure a lot of people will miss it. I have submitted an edit to fix it.